# If response redirect = true

Tags: c#, winforms

I send POST to a url and if the response has redirect with url(which contains jsessionid) it will be true? else false.

How to write it?

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public bool od_auth(string login, string pass)
        {
            string HTML = PostData("");
            
            return true;
        }

        private void Auth_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string login = textBox1.Text;
            string pass = textBox2.Text;
            bool avt = od_auth(login, pass);
        }
        public static string PostData(string file, string data)
        {
            var cookies = new CookieContainer();
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(file);
            request.Method = "POST";
            request.CookieContainer = cookies;
            request.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
            request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            byte[] EncodedPostParams = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data);
            request.ContentLength = EncodedPostParams.Length;
            request.GetRequestStream().Write(EncodedPostParams,
                                             0,
                                             EncodedPostParams.Length);
            request.GetRequestStream().Close();
            HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
            string html = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream(),
                                           Encoding.UTF8).ReadToEnd();
            return html;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should check the response.StatusCode :

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.statuscode.aspx )

and test for a redirect status code (301, 302, 303):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/aa383887%28en-us,VS.85%29.aspx

as noted by @hvd, this should not work because of `request.AllowAutoRedirect = true;`.

You should :

- set `request.AllowAutoRedirect = false;`
- check for the response.StatusCode
- set your boolean depending if it is a redirect status code
- build a new request, based on "Location" and retrieve its response

BTW, if you have nothing to add to the second request, maybe you could just compare the response.ResponseUri with `file` to see if the response might have been redirected

Comment: The code in the question sets `AllowAutoRedirect = true;`, so how could the returned status code ever be 30x? If it's 30x, then the redirect should already have been followed, a new request sent, and that new request's status code is what `response.StatusCode` should show.

Comment: @hvd : you're right, thx. I overlooked the question. Will complete my answer.